# How to avoid hydration error on a date string without using useEffect or dynamic import?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dayjs

My page content loads so much faster when using server components and I would like to avoid using useEffect or dynamic import for handling a date string. Is there a way to fix this and avoid the hydration error without resorting to useEffect or dynamic import?

Fx. date from Supabase: `2023-07-18 17:34:59.293312+00`

```
  const postDate: string = parseDate(post.created_at);

  <span>{postDate}</span>
```

Date parse:

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import relativeTime from "dayjs/plugin/relativeTime";

export function parseDate(date: Post["created_at"]): string {
 dayjs.extend(relativeTime);
 const xParsedDate = dayjs(date);

 const diffInMs = dayjs().diff(xParsedDate);
 const diffInMin = dayjs().diff(xParsedDate, "minute");
 const diffInHours = dayjs().diff(xParsedDate, "hour");
 const diffInDays = dayjs().diff(xParsedDate, "day");

 let parsedDate = "";

 if (diffInMs < 60000) {
    parsedDate = dayjs().to(xParsedDate);
  } else if (diffInMin < 60) {
    parsedDate = xParsedDate.fromNow();
  } else if (diffInHours < 24) {
    parsedDate = xParsedDate.fromNow();
  } else if (diffInDays < 365) {
    parsedDate = xParsedDate.format("D MMMM");
  } else {
    parsedDate = xParsedDate.format("D MMMM YYYY");
  }

 return parsedDate;
}
```